# xmlconvert string to date

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, xmltype, xmlroot

I have model:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "event", IsNullable=true)]
public class Event
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public eventArtists artists { get; set; }
    public venue venue { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get;set;}
    public string description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("image")]
    public List<string> image { get; set; }
    public int attendance { get; set; }
    public int reviews { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string tickets { get; set; }
    public int cancelled { get; set; }
    [XmlArray(ElementName="tags")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="tag")]
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
}
```

now I want to convert public string startDate { get;set;} to DatiTime:

```
public DateTime startDate { get{return startDate;} set{startDate. = DateTime.Parse(startDate);}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have anything special to do, just declare the property as a `DateTime`. The XmlSerializer will convert it automatically to a string like `2012-03-27T16:21:12.8135895+02:00`

If you need to use a specific format, you have to use a small trick... Put a `[XmlIgnore]` attribute on the `DateTime` property, and add a new string property that handles the formatting:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime startDate { get;set;}

private const string DateTimeFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";

[XmlElement("startDate")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string startDateXml
{
    get { return startDate.ToString(DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    set { startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
}
```

(the `[EditorBrowsable]` attribute is there to avoid showing the property in intellisense, since it's only useful for serialization)

Comment: Exception: The string 'Fri, 30 Mar 2012 20:00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value.